# "ReferenceError: $ is not defined " while trying to use datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap-3

while i am trying to use date function of bootstrap i am getting this error **ReferenceError: $ is not defined**
my html code is like

```
<div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
    <label><b>Start Date</b>
       <input type='text' name="start_date" id="start_date" class="form-control" required />
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
</div>
```

i used several link in the bottom of html

```
<!-- basic scripts -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--For Date Time-->
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>  
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
```

i used this datepicker and datetimepicker several time.. Sometimes they work sometime they don't...is there is any way to use date by not getting any trouble. my date picker function is like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    /*$(function () {
        $('#start_date').datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
        });

        $('#end_date').datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
        });
    });*/

    $(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
            format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
        });

        $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
            format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Maybe noConflict is on, try using `jQuery` instead of `$`

Comment: You're loading three different versions of jQuery and overwriting the previous on each time. Pick **one** version jQuery and load **only** that one version. Then start trying to figure out why you code doesn't work.

Comment: why you have added 3 jquery references?

Comment: Er... @vijayP There are only two.

Comment: @PraveenKumar — 1.11, 1.7 and 1.10

Comment: no @PraveenKumar ..there are 3 ref: `jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js`, `js/jquery-1.7.1.js` and `//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js`

Comment: Please provide a [proper test case](http://sscce.org/) showing how the three chunks of code you have releate to each other. I suspect a script element ordering issue, but there isn't enough evidence in the question to really prove it.

Comment: Please do not include different versions of jQuery, and if you are planning to do so, with a valid reason, make sure they don't conflict with each other, by giving a `.noConflict`. It is definitely sure that there's a `.noConflict` at the end.

Comment: i used all the link in the bottom of html...and i tried one by one...none 0f them work......

Comment: @mishir.ali — Again: How do your three bits of code relate to each other? Put them *together* in a *single* test case.

Answer (score 2):

I know this a little old. I realized after having this same issue, the reason it doesn't work is because there is an order in which things have to be loaded.

1. Jquery
2. Bootstrap
3. Renderbody()
4. Moment.js
5. datetimepicker js

Also ensure that you only have 1 jquery version installed as well.

Answer (score 1):

You are using three versions of jQuery, and the latter cleared out the plugins:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>  
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script> <!-- this is attached to 1.7.1 -->
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script> <!-- remove this -->
```

Please do not include different versions of jQuery, and if you are planning to do so, with a valid reason, make sure they don't conflict with each other, by giving a `.noConflict`. It is definitely sure that there's a `.noConflict` at the end.

Comment: That might explain an error message that said `$.datetimepicker ` was undefined, but the question says that `$` is undefined.

Comment: @Quentin Ah yeah... Could be.

Comment: @GennadiyLitvinyuk Yes yes yes, clarified.

Comment: i used all the link in the bottom of html...and i tried one by one...none of them work.

Comment: @mishir.ali What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: just trying to get a date..and based on that date..i will get data from database

Comment: @mishir.ali Can you do this? Please remove all the jQuery and jQuery UI references leaving the first two. Tell me if it works. You have added them thrice.

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

i guess this is my solution...tnx everyone